# Resize desktop icons

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to re-size the desktop icons with C#. I'm not finding much with my various searches. Has anyone done this before. I know the size is stored in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size registry value but changing this value doesn't seem to actually change the size of the desktop icons.

Answer (score 1):

After setting that registry value, you need to flush the icon cache, thus:

```
::SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_SETTINGCHANGE,SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS,NULL);
```